# Write a function firstWord, taking a string and returning the first word in that string. The first word are all characters up to the first space

Tags: javascript

```
function firstWord (go and run) {
 let text = "go and run";
 let firstBlank = text.substr(0, 2);
 return firstBlank;
 }
```

Why is this giving me wrong answer? Can any one explain the solution please?
hint:-

```
function firstWord(s) {
  let firstBlank = s.indexOf(' ');
  return s.substr(0, firstBlank);
}
```

Comment: First of all, [`substr`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is deprecated. Don’t use it. Next, consider what happens when the input is `"word"`. Read the docs: [`indexOf`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [`substring`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [`split`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`).

Comment: @SebastianSimon is right - also explain what trouble you had with your first attempt? what was wrong with the result?

Comment: Related: [How to grab substring before a specified character jQuery or JavaScript](/q/9133102/4642212).

Comment: `go and run` is not a valid parameter declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- `go and run` is not a valid parameter declaration in the function header. There is confusion here with the parameter and the string value that you expect the function to be called with. In the function header you should list the parameter(s) with variable names. Since the function should be called by passing a string, you could name that variable `phrase`, or `text` or something else that is descriptive.
- `let text = "go and run";` should not appear in the function. The function should work for *any* string, so it should not be hard-coded to "go and run". The parameter variable will have the actual string that the function is called with.
- `let firstBlank = text.substr(0, 2);` is again focusing on *one particular* string. It actually doesn't search for a space at all. You -- as programmer -- tell it that the first word is 2 characters long. Your function then might as well just do `return "go"`. But you should really support *any* string, and then let the code find out how long the first word is by scanning the string for the first space or end of the string.
- [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) (also in the second code block) is a deprecated function. Use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) instead.

The second code snippet does the job better, but it still goes wrong when the given string only contains one word. In that case, it will return the wrong answer.

Here is a correction to that second function, but using a more descriptive parameter variable:

```
function firstWord(text) {
  let firstBlank = text.indexOf(' ');
  if (firstBlank == -1) { // There is no space at all -- return the whole string
    return text;
  } 
  return text.slice(0, firstBlank);
}
```

NB: Using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) a shorter solution code is possible.